# React Counter Error

Tags: reactjs

When I click to '+' counter works, it's ok! But when I click to 'add element' my counter strays! It does not move with others elements like frozen! I think that call context is true, I don't see any mistakes. Please help!

```js
const data = [
 { id: 2, name: 'element'},
 { id: 1, name: 'element'},
 { id: 0, name: 'element'}
]

const appendItem = () => {
  data.unshift({
    id: data.length,
    name: 'element'
  })
  render()
}

class Counter extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }
  handleClick = () => this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  render() {
    return <span>
      {this.state.count}
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>+</button>
    </span>
  }
}

const ListItem =
  (item, idx) => 
    <li key={idx}>{item.id} - {item.name} - <Counter /></li>

const List =
 ({ data }) =>
   <ul>
      {data.map(ListItem)}
    </ul>

const ListContainer = 
 () =>
   <div>
     <List data={data}/>
      <button onClick={appendItem}>add element</button>
    </div>

  const render = 
    () =>
      ReactDOM.render(<ListContainer />, document.getElementById('container'))

  render()
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because  `<Counter/>` is out of sync with `data`, it's not part of `data` So when a `data` gets a new element, it will render the `<li>` plus the old `<Counter />` 
Also the `<Counter />` component is not really updating (since no props change and no setState is invoked), so when data updates, the DOM of counters remains the same.

Also with your approach there are some problems:

- the data and the addItem function should be inside of some component
- since the `count` is inside of Counter as a private state, you will not be able to use it (unless it dispatch an action with flux architecture)

Your `data` array should be a state inside of `<ListContainer />`

```
this.state = { data : [
    { id: 2, name: 'element', count: 0},
    { id: 1, name: 'element', count: 0},
    { id: 0, name: 'element', count: 0}
]
}
```

and pass the count as props to `Counter`

I created a very similar code other day, it may help you [Codepen](http://codepen.io/kossel/pen/VmPzbW)

Comment: Great! Thank you!